# after clicking a button, get the value of selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a button that opens a modal and performs ajax to populate the fields...........

```
    $(document).on('click', '.renew', function(){
            var user_id3 = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
            url:"fetch.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{user_id3:user_id3},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
              $('#businessModal').modal('show');
              $('#requested_by').val(data.requested_by);
              $('#form_type').val(data.form_type);
              $('#bus_type').find('option[value="'+data.bid+'"]').prop('selected', true);   
            }
          })

        //the code that i tried
        var val = $('#bus_type').find(":selected").val();
        alert(value);
  });//END
```

i want to get the value of selected option after clicking the button, but on the **first** click of button the value that I always get is the **first option** of the select, but on the second click i already get the value of selected option

```
//select option
 <label>Type of Business</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="bus_type" id="bus_type">
            <?php 
              foreach ($result as $value) {
                echo "<option value=".$value['id'].">".strtoupper($value['name'])."</option>";
              }
            ?>                   
      </select>
```

Comment: The AJAX request is asynchronous, therefore you're trying to get the selected value of `#bus_type` *before* it has been set. Move your last two lines of code *inside* the `success` function block.

Comment: No inconvenience, we're all here to learn :) I'd suggest you research how AJAX works, as it will help you. With regard to making a second AJAX request after the first one, you will need to make it from the `success` handler function, as that is the *only* place where you can guarantee that the AJAX logic has been completed.

Comment: thanks dude i got it already.

Comment: i deleted my previous comments because i got it already. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an async problem. You are trying to get the selected option before the ajax call has finished and selected an option, so by default the first option is the "selected" one. You need to modify your code like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.renew', function(){
        var user_id3 = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
        url:"fetch.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{user_id3:user_id3},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data)
        {
          $('#businessModal').modal('show');
          $('#requested_by').val(data.requested_by);
          $('#form_type').val(data.form_type);
          $('#bus_type').find('option[value="'+data.bid+'"]').prop('selected', true);   

          // this needs to be here
          var val = $('#bus_type').find(":selected").val();
          alert(value);
        }
      })

});//END
```